# Find the max value from previous row

Tags: sql, impala

I want to find in the below rows the maximum "*book_type*" value:

| book_id | book_type | book_time | uniq_step | book_ordered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2022-10-13 00:00:00 | 800 | 0 |
| 1 |  | 2022-10-13 00:00:00 | 801 | 0 |
| 1 | poetry | 2022-10-13 00:00:00 | 802 | 1 |
| 1 |  | 2022-10-13 00:00:00 | 803 | 0 |
| 1 |  | 2022-10-13 01:00:00 | 804 | 0 |
| 1 | poetry | 2022-10-13 01:00:00 | 802 | 1 |

I want in the line with `uniq_step = 804` to have as `book_type = poetry` but when I use the LAG window function I am getting ' ' (the space string).

So is there any way to take from the partition by book_time the max value as a lag?

Comment: Does your query have to work only for `uniq_step = 804`? Can you share your current query?

Comment: @lemon   Its not only for 804. It is an example.

Comment: have you tried using other window functions other than `LAG`?

Comment: No, only lag and lead I tried. Are you suggesting anything else?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `LAST_VALUE` window function in place of the `LAG` one. Since your "*book_type*" values can't be `NULL` in your specific case, you can use a `CASE` statement inside the window function to make them NULL.

```
LAST_VALUE(CASE WHEN book_type <> "" THEN book_type END) OVER(
    PARTITION BY book_id 
    ORDER     BY uniq_step
)
```

Side Note: Empty spaces/strings are still values in a DBMS. If you have the possibility of refactoring the empty values in your db to NULL values, that will make the DBMS handle your data better than how it does now.